# SQL Query gets executed extremly slow after adding one more OR

Tags: sql, sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I have encountered this issue where I had to add another Table to the search query to fullfill my customers needs.

The search results are correct and all but if the search word is 3 or less characters long the search process takes 5 seconds (tested directly on the SSMS tool on the server)

The query looks like this :

```
SELECT 
    Kundendaten$.ID, 
    Kundendaten$.firmenname1, 
    Kundendaten$.firmenname2, 
    Kundendaten$.strasse, 
    Kundendaten$.uid, 
    Kundendaten$.lkw12t, 
    Kundendaten$.lkw3t, 
    Kundendaten$.gesperrt 
FROM Kundendaten$
LEFT JOIN Kundentyp$ ON Kundendaten$.ID = Kundentyp$.Kunden_ID
WHERE Kundentyp$.ext_kdnr LIKE '%nox%'
   OR ( 
          Kundendaten$.firmenname1 LIKE '%nox%'
       OR Kundendaten$.firmenname2 LIKE '%nox%'
       OR Kundendaten$.suchwort LIKE '%nox%'
       OR Kundendaten$.gehr_kundennummer LIKE '%nox%'
       OR Kundendaten$.kundenummer LIKE '%nox%'
       OR Kundendaten$.uid LIKE '%nox%'
       OR Kundendaten$.ID LIKE '%nox%'
   )
ORDER BY Kundendaten$.ID ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

The issue with the long waiting time occurs since I have added the table "Kundentyp$.ext_kdnr" statement

But then again, if the search keyword is more specific the search takes only a few ms..

I have no idea how to debug this ^^

Comment: sorry i mistakenly added my sql . It is SQL SERVER

Comment: Move the Kundentyp$.ext_kdnr LIKE condition from WHERE clause to ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN behavior. As it is now it executes as a regular inner join.

Comment: Have you checked that there is an index on all the columns you're searching ?

Comment: @cosmo0 yes there is

Comment: @jarlh could you write it down for me ? I am not quite sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Compare query plans between queries (CTRL-L). Does the new table have a lot of rows? can you remove the `ext_kdnr LIKE` portion to determine whether it is  the like ot the join that is the issue?

Comment: an index won't help for a `LIKE '%` search - check the query plan to confirm

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid when I remove the ext_kdnr LIKE all queries get executed instantly again, regardless if its a 3 character search or exact search. The main table "Kundendaten$" has 5k rows and the new joined table has 2k rows

Comment: OK so now you've isolated the issue further. Note the prior comment - you are effectively doing an `INNER JOIN` so either change to an inner join or move the where to the ON clause, like this: `ON Kundendaten$.ID = Kundentyp$.Kunden_ID AND Kundentyp$.ext_kdnr LIKE '%nox% WHERE ('`

Comment: Try this:
FROM Kundendaten$
LEFT JOIN Kundentyp$ 
ON Kundendaten$.ID = Kundentyp$.Kunden_ID
AND Kundentyp$.ext_kdnr LIKE '%nox%'
WHERE....

Comment: for 2K and 3K rows I would not expect any performance issues at all.

Comment: Job done. Appears that the LEFT JOIN got really executed wrong and the change to INNER JOIN fixed the problem. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the great help of fellow stackoverflowers' I could solve the issue.

The problem was, that the `LEFT JOIN` got executed as an `inner join` in my query and may have caused a conflict.

A simple change to `INNER JOIN` fixed my performance issue